# How to show all categories and their subcategories on Layered Navigation?

Tags: category, magento2.2, layered-navigation

I am using Mageplaza Layered Navigation module to show categories and their subcategories but its only showing subcategories.

I want to show all categories and their subcategories like below format -

**Category 1**

-Subcategory 1-1

-Subcategory 1-2

-Subcategory 1-3

**Category 2**

-Subcategory 2-1

-Subcategory 2-1

-Subcategory 2-3

But its only showing subcategories if I select Category 1

-Subcategory 1-1

-Subcategory 1-2

-Subcategory 1-3

Below is the code which returns me only subcategories

> app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php

```
protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        if (!$this->_moduleHelper->isEnabled()) {
            return parent::_getItemsData();
        }

        /** @var \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();

        if ($this->_isFilter) {
            $productCollection = $productCollection->getCollectionClone()
                ->removeAttributeSearch('category_ids');
        }

        $optionsFacetedData = $productCollection->getFacetedData('category');
        $category           = $this->dataProvider->getCategory();

        $categories         = $category->getChildrenCategories();        

        $collectionSize = $productCollection->getSize();

        if ($category->getIsActive()) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
               $count = isset($optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]) ? $optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]['count'] : 0;
                if ($category->getIsActive()
                    && $this->_moduleHelper->getFilterModel()->isOptionReducesResults($this, $count, $collectionSize)
                ) {                    
                    $this->itemDataBuilder->addItemData(
                        $this->escaper->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                        $category->getId(),
                        $count
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->itemDataBuilder->build();
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to show all categories and their subcategories on layered navigation?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Thanks for your kind help. I have installed SEBWITE plugin and configured as per given suggestion but its showing only title as "Categories" on category col.left sidebar nothing else. Do you have any idea about it - What may cause behind this?